# React.js - Functional component with useState hook doesn't re-render as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is a bit of an open ended question, as I'm sure the way I'm going about this is incorrect. But I'm curious why React isn't re-rendering as I would expect. I suspect it has to do with the behavior of the `useState` hook paired with a functional component.

The code is in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/foos-and-bars-hierarchy-example-wqi0s) link, and code noted below:

```
function App() {
  var foosList = ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"];

  const [selectedFoo, setSelectedFoo] = useState(-1);
  const isSelected = i => i === selectedFoo;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FoosWrapper>
        <TitleSpan>Foos</TitleSpan>
        <ListGroup>
          {foosList.map((fooItem, i) => (
            <ListGroupItem
              key={fooItem}
              active={isSelected(i)}
              onClick={() => setSelectedFoo(i)}
            >
              {fooItem}
            </ListGroupItem>
          ))}
        </ListGroup>
      </FoosWrapper>
      <BarsWrapper>
        <TitleSpan>Bars</TitleSpan>
        <Bars foo={foosList[selectedFoo]} />
      </BarsWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}

const Bars = props => {
  const [pendingBar, setPendingBar] = useState("");
  const [newBars, setNewBars] = useState([]);

  const keyPress = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      save(pendingBar);
    }
  };

  const save = bar => {
    newBars.push(bar);
    setNewBars([...newBars]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ListGroup>
        <ListGroupItem key={props.foo}>{props.foo}</ListGroupItem>
      </ListGroup>
      <ListGroup>
        {newBars.map(newBar => (
          <ListGroupItem key={newBar}>{newBar}</ListGroupItem>
        ))}
      </ListGroup>
      <InputGroup>
        <Input
          placeholder="Add a bar"
          onChange={e => setPendingBar(e.target.value)}
          onKeyPress={keyPress}
        />
      </InputGroup>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Broadly, there are two logical widgets: `Foos` and `Bars`. `Foos` on the left, `Bars`, on the right. I'd like to have a user select a 'foo', and a distinct list of bars associated with said 'foo' is displayed on the right. A user may add new bars to each respective 'foo'. Can think of `foo` having a parent relationship to `bar`.

The `Bars` component maintains a list of bars added by the user. My expectation is the `Bars` component would re-render the internal `newBars` collection when a new foo is selected. However, that state hangs around and is displayed regardless of what 'foo' is selected on the lefthand side.

That seems weird, but perhaps I'm not thinking of React functional components and hooks in the right way. Would love to understand why this behavior exists, and additional would love to hear proposed approaches that make more sense.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Can think of foo having a parent relationship to bar." This relation has no reflection in your code. You have 2 separate arrays for foos and for bars. You expectation is right `Bars` component got rerender when you change `foo` but `useState` would not reinitialize a new state (because this would not be a state). If you want to recreate state use key https://codesandbox.io/s/foos-and-bars-hierarchy-example-wqi0s but this would wipe bars on foo change. Or  lift bars to `App` state if you want to actually have the relation between foo and bars.

Comment: ^^^ correct link demonstrating key usage https://codesandbox.io/s/foos-and-bars-hierarchy-example-rvoqq haven't saved changes :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the hierarchy to be reflected, then initialize the state of your bars so that it synchronizes with the state of your foos. Right now, your `Bars` is a single component maintaining its own state independently of `App`. Here's how I would approach this particular relationship.

```
function App() {
  const foos = useMemo(() => ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"], []);
  const [bars, setBars] = useState(foos.map(() => []));
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
  const setBar = useCallback(
    bar => {
      setBars(bars => Object.assign(
        [...bars],
        { [selectedIndex]: bar }
      ));
    },
    [setBars, selectedIndex]
  );
  const isSelected = useCallback(
    index => index === selectedIndex,
    [selectedIndex]
  );
  const foosList = useMemo(
    () => foos.map((foo, index) => (
      <ListGroupItem
        key={foo}
        active={isSelected(index)}
        onClick={() => setSelectedIndex(index)}
      >
        {foo}
      </ListGroupItem>
    )),
    [foos, isSelected, setSelectedIndex]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FoosWrapper>
        <TitleSpan>Foos</TitleSpan>
        <ListGroup>{foosList}</ListGroup>
      </FoosWrapper>
      <BarsWrapper>
        <TitleSpan>Bars</TitleSpan>
        <Bars
          foo={foos[selectedIndex]}
          bars={bars[selectedIndex]}
          setBars={setBar}
        />
      </BarsWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}

function Bars({ foo, bars, setBars }) {
  const [pendingBar, setPendingBar] = useState("");
  const barsList = useMemo(
    () => bars.map(bar => (
      <ListGroupItem key={bar}>{bar}</ListGroupItem>
    )),
    [bars]
  );
  const save = useCallback(
    bar => { setBars([...bars, bar]); },
    [setBars, bars]
  );
  const change = useCallback(
    event => { setPendingBar(event.target.value); },
    [setPendingBar]
  );
  const keyPress = useCallback(
    event => { if (event.key === "Enter") save(pendingBar); },
    [pendingBar, save]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <ListGroup>
        <ListGroupItem key={foo}>{foo}</ListGroupItem>
      </ListGroup>
      <ListGroup>{barsList}</ListGroup>
      <InputGroup>
        <Input
          placeholder="Add a bar"
          onChange={change}
          onKeyPress={keyPress}
        />
      </InputGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit foos and bars hierarchy example]

I may have gone a bit overboard with the memoization hooks, but that should give you at least an idea of what and how various values can be memoized.

Keep in mind that the second argument is the array of dependencies which determines whether the memoized value is recomputed or retrieved from cache. The dependencies of hooks are checked by reference, much like a `PureComponent`.

I also opted to initialize `selectedIndex` to `0` to avoid addressing the issue of how to handle the render function for `Bars` when no `foo` is selected. I'll leave that as an exercise to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the bars for the selected foo, you need to structure your "bars" data accordingly. The simplest way to do this is to keep the "bars" data in the format of an object instead of an array. You can write the code as below.

```
const Bars = props => {
    const [pendingBar, setPendingBar] = useState("");
    const [newBars, setNewBars] = useState({});
    const { foo } = props;

    const keyPress = e => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            save(pendingBar);
        }
    };

    const save = bar => {
        if (!foo) {
            console.log("Foo is not selected");
            return;
        }
        const bars = newBars[foo] || [];
        bars.push(bar);
        setNewBars({
            ...newBars,
            [foo]: [...bars]
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <ListGroup>
                <ListGroupItem key={props.foo}>{props.foo}</ListGroupItem>
            </ListGroup>
            <ListGroup>
                {newBars[foo] &&
                    newBars[foo].map(newBar => (
                        <ListGroupItem key={newBar}>{newBar}</ListGroupItem>
                    ))}
            </ListGroup>
            <InputGroup>
                <Input
                    placeholder="Add a bar"
                    onChange={e => setPendingBar(e.target.value)}
                    onKeyPress={keyPress}
                />
            </InputGroup>
        </div>
    );
};
```